# Ansible module documentation on RTD?

Tags: ansible, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

We have a set of Ansible modules on GitHub (https://github.com/zhmcclient/zhmc-ansible-modules) and can generate HTML documentation from it using Sphinx. However, the build process includes a step where a documentationgenerator tool from Ansible is run to generate .rst files from the Python module source.

We have set up an RTD project for this (http://zhmc-ansible-modules.readthedocs.io/), but that extra step is not run there, of course.

-> How can we get that extra step run within the build process that runs on RTD?

Answer (score 1):

RTD does not support intermediary steps in its build process. You must provide source files in your repository that are ready to be rendered. See [RTD Build Process](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builds.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was afraid of that being the case ... Our solution is now to check in the generated .rst files for the Ansible modules, and to have a check in the Travis CI run as to whether these .rst files are up to date w.r.t. the module source files.